# Change org-log-done setting only for a subtree

Tags: org-mode

In my configuration, I have:

```
(setq org-log-done 'time)
```

However, for one particular subtree, I want to suppress this behavior. So, closing any items here will not record a time.

Can this be done by setting some property for the heading? Or any other method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by setting the local property `LOGGING` to `nil` (usually by pressing `C-c C-x p`):

```
* No logging section
  :PROPERTIES:
  :LOGGING:  nil
  :END:
** DONE A task
```

See [Tracking TODO stage changes](https://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-TODO-state-changes.html#Tracking-TODO-state-changes) in the manual.

Comment: Thanks. That was perfect.